# Prevent setting selectedKeys to sap.m.MultiComboBox from triggering change event on intitialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, sapui5, javascript-databinding

I have my `MultiComboBox` attached to a list of key value pairs.

When I bind my box to my data it works, and setting selected keys works, but unfortunately this triggers a change event.

Each change event triggers a HTTP request, hence my problem.

```
   var oMultiComboBox = new sap.m.MultiComboBox({
     selectedKeys: {
        path: "oModel>/foo",
        formatter: function(oContext){

 // is an array of integers, MultiComboBox demands keys to be strings

        for (var i = 0; i < aValue.length; i++){
        aValue[i] = aValue[i].toString();

            };
        return aValue;
          }

           }
        });

   oMultiComboBox.bindAggregation("items", {
     path: "oModel>/bar",
     factory: function(sId, oContext) {
     return new sap.ui.core.Item({
     key: oContext.getProperty("myKey"),
     text: oContext.getProperty("myText"),
         });
        }
     });

    oMultiComboBox.attachChange(function(oEvent){
    //jQuery.ajax request
    });
```